# gravatar_image_tag breaks after upgrading to Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, gravatar

I use gravatar_image_tag to generate user avatars. It works perfectly fine in Rails 3.0.10, but breaks when I upgrade to Rails 3.1.0. Unfortunately, it doesn't produce any error message/warning. It just stops showing images. I have no clue how to debug this.

I know this is very limited information, but hopefully someone who ran into this issue before may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you successfully migrated everything to 3.1? The changes are very significant because of the introduction of the Asset Pipeline post 3.1. If you're using the `gravatar_image_tag` gem, chances are, you have not yet successfully migrated.

Comment: My upgrade is mostly successful (I follow RailsCasts tutorial on upgrading to Rails 3.1 religiously), except for some broken images due to new image_tag syntax. Could you please explain why if I still use gravatar_image_tag gem then I have not yet successfully migrated? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that in Rails 3.0, I can write:

```
        - link_to(@user) do
          = avatar_for(@user, size = 80)
```

but in Rails 3.1, I have to write:

```
        = link_to(@user) do
          = avatar_for(@user, size = 80)
```

This is the reason why gravatar_image_tag doesn't work for me after upgrading to Rails 3.1